# Бот в дискорде неправильно выдает роли

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

```
if int(cursor.fetchall()[4][0]) > 500:
                role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "some role")
                await member.add_roles(role)
            if int(cursor.fetchall()[4][0]) > 1000:
                role1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "some role")
                role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "some role")
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await member.remove_roles(role1)
```

Вот код. Подключена бд sqlite3, в которой хранится баланс пользователя. Выше приведен код для конкретного пользователя одного. Я достаю его баланс, сравниваю с числом, и если он больше 500, выдаю соответтвующую роль. Далее проверяю больше ли его баланс тысячи. Если да, то удаляю предыдущую и добавляю новую. Так вот, когда проверяю работу, выполняется только первая. Вложить вторую проверку в первую пробовал, не помогло. Если ввожу значение, к примеру 600, он выдает первую. Если далее вввожу еще 500(в сумме 1100), он все оставляет как и было. Если было 0 и я сходу ввел 1100 Он все равно выдает первую роль, а во вторую проверку даже не заходит. Проверок будет штук 6, как мне организовать все так, что бы он проверял все??

Comment: Во-первых, стоит проверить остальной код на возможность воздействия на данный кусочек кода.


Во-вторых, возможно вы не правильно собираете баланс пользователя.


В-третьих, если дело не в первых двух замечаниях, то виновата конструкция await скорее всего.

Comment: Дело определенно не в первых двух пунктах, так как если закомментировать первую проверку и добавить к балансу значение, после которого баланс станет больше 1000 бот добавит новую роль и удалит старую. Как будто бы бот видит только первую проверку, а все остальные за ней нет